# url rewrite in web.config

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

I've been reading articles regarding Url Rewrite in web.config but I don't understand why my redirection doesn't work. Below is my sample url:

```
localhost/MySite/1542
```

and here's the pattern I used for matching the url:

```
<rule name="testRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^/MySite/([0-9]+)" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="/MySite/default.html" />
</rule>
```

can someone enlighten me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

try removing the leading `/` in matching url `^MySite/([0-9]+)`

```
<rule name="testRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^MySite/([0-9]+)" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="/MySite/default.html" />
</rule>
```