# URL Rewriting in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, redirect

I want to only rewrite my url like

```
http://sifweb/about-us/Open-Article/ArtMID/7821/ArticleID/1132/Nirmal-test
```

to

```
http://sifweb/about-us/Open-Article/Something
```

But want to redirect same old url just want to rewrite url in browser.

I referred below links

[IIS URL Rewrite and Web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410067/iis-url-rewrite-and-web-config)

[url rewrite in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445529/url-rewrite-in-web-config)

Comment: Can you provide few examples of your URLs, because i am confused that you wrote `Something` in your url. What does it mean?

Comment: Dotnetnuke does not work that way. You cannot just rewrite url's. As you can see there are two ID's in the url that are needed to find the correct article.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom url provider for modules that don't include them.  Check the Community Blog for some discussion, and there are example providers in Github.

Google "dnn url provider" for some links.